# Get entries stored in database from yesterday

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I have an SQL statement that gets me some data based on today's date and it fills it in linkbutton.Text. If there is not enough data for today, it should fill it with the data from yesterday. Here is the SQL statement I've written so far:

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE cat = 1 and datee = @dt ORDER BY datee DESC ";
```

Comment: Would be best to drop the `datee` where clause and just add a `TOP(x)` selection to get how many results you deem to be acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could use `BETWEEN` aside from `TOP` statement like:

```
SELECT TOP(10) * FROM table1 WHERE cat = 1 and  
datee BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, @dt) AND @dt 
ORDER BY datee DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rather than limiting the date, just decide how many results you want and select the `TOP(x)` number of them:

For example, if you want the 20 most recent results starting today and going back to tomorrow (and further) if needed, you can do this:

```
"SELECT TOP(20) * FROM table1 WHERE cat = 1 ORDER BY datee DESC ";
```

If you pottentially have dates in the future you can limit them by adding the following where clause:

```
"SELECT TOP(20) * FROM table1 WHERE cat = 1 AND datee <= @dt  ORDER BY datee DESC ";
```

Where `@dt` is Today's date

---

Of course if you rules are more specific, i.e you should return 24 results if Today has 24 entries, or you don't want the total restricted in such a way, then I would suggest doing two queries, for example:

```
var results = GetResultsForToday();

if(results.Count() < 20)//not enough!
    result.Add(GetResultsForYesterday());
```